# Calendar primefaces column filter

Tags: java, jsf-2, filter, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable in Primefaces 3.3. One of the columns is a date. I want to have a calendar filter field instead of the regular filter field Primefaces provides so the users can search all items in the list that have that specific date.